# How do I export the files of TempleOS to the host operating system?

Tags: templeos

How do I export my files from the running root partition of a TempleOS install? I would like to be able to browse them in Linux. I'm using Virtual Box and have TempleOS mounted as root.

On [this website](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Home/Web/LineRep.html#l519), I can see they've managed to do that. But, I would like to that to my running install.

Comment: Because the OS doesn't support networking, you are limited to accessing its HDD through your hypervisor. What filesystem did you use to install it? What have you tried? If you've mounted the drive already, what errors are you getting when you attempt to view the files? Are you trying to view the files, or do you want to move them elsewhere for inspection? The term "export" in your title and question are unclear.

Comment: TempleOS uses it's own fs called Red Sea. What's the difference between viewing the files (outside of TempleOS) and moving them elsewhere for inspection?

Comment: According to documentation, it also supports FAT32. Your issue then is that you need to find a file system driver to allow Linux to read the Red Sea file system. If you'd set up the drive as FAT32 to begin with you wouldn't have any trouble reading the drive as Linux supports that out of the bag.

Comment: If TempleOS supports FAT32, can't you connect an external FAT32 drive and have TempleOS copy the files to that drive?  Then that drive could be read by Linux, Windows, etc.  I'm assuming TempleOS doesn't have its own file formats.  If that was the case, you would have another hurdle.

Comment: The OS doesn't support networking at all so fixer1234 is the only option.  Make a USB stick FAT32, partition, or hard drive.  Mount it, copy files onto it.  unmount.  Mount it from outside the OS.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read any File System (FS), the Operating System (OS) must have a driver that instructs the OS how to communicate with that FS.

That is likely the root issue here as well, and TempleOS' status makes it unlikely there is much development focused on showing other, more mainstream, OSes read the Red Sea FS.

There was only one result on Google that looked promising, and that is this GitHub repository: https://github.com/minexew/TempleOS/tree/master/redseafs

You'll need to install FUSE on your Debian/Ubuntu system, and then you should be able to mount the Red Sea FS volumes and read them.

Answer (score 0):

Since FAT32 has already been covered, here is the only other alternative.

This will be hard. incredible hard.

Since for networking you have to not only implement hardware drivers, but the whole OSI stack, its not practical.

Add a COM port

If you get lucky it has COM support, but don't count on it.

1. Otherwise you have to implement a COM port in the kernel either by writing the code yourself or porting someone else's code over.  Set the speed for 115200 or as fast as possible.
2. Then, another hard task implement X/Y/Zmodem.

However, compared to the effort of implementing as network stack this is easy.

This was the only option for old computers.  The TI/994A has only this option.

On the PC side you can find old software to handle these file transfers already written.